# Maven: How show in terminal the abort message of a JUnit Assumption?

Tags: maven, junit, maven-3, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

Using `JUnit 5`, about **Assumptions** the `assumeTrue` and `assumeFalse` methods can define an abort message if the *condition* fails. Even when the Assumption fails the `@Test` method passes, through either Eclipse or STS4 appears the following message as an abort:

```
org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException: Assumption failed: -Dspring.application.context.reporte is not 'true'
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions.throwAssumptionFailed(Assumptions.java:316)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions.assumeTrue(Assumptions.java:101)
    at ...
    ...
```

Through Maven how could be possible show the *abort message* too? Currently does not show nothing and test passes, about the `surefire-plugin` it is declared as:

```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.2</version>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: I strongly recommend to upgrade to the most recent version of maven-surefire-plugin (3.0.0) and retry that... also would it be helpful to see the code of your test?

Comment: Thanks, it has been just released at _Mar 14, 2023_ according with https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin

Comment: I know that ... I prefer to use this location: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: Thanks I forgot that source ...