# correct configuration of maven-surefire-plugin 3 to show @DisplayName and TestAbortedException of JUnit 5

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

For `JUnit` **5** Having the following Test class:

```java
@DisplayName("Testing Multiple 'findById' Test Methods - Environment 'assumeTrue'")
class CientificoServiceFindByIdWithSystemEnvironmentAssumeTrueTests {

    private CientificoService cientificoService;

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() {
        System.out.println("******************");
        System.out.println("Creando Aplicacion");
        System.out.println("******************");
        AplicacionFactory.createAplicacion();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach() {
        System.out.println("[Obteniendo CientificoService]");
        cientificoService = AplicacionFactory.getCientificoService();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Testing 'findById' with 'id' 1 - Environment 'assumeTrue' Case 01")
    void findByIdWithId1EnvironmentAssumeTrueCase01Test() {
        System.out.println(" findByIdWithId1EnvironmentAssumeTrueCase01Test - Inicio");
        System.out.println(" JAVA_HOME: " + System.getenv("JAVA_HOME"));
        assumeTrue(System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") != null, "JAVA_HOME must exist");
        System.out.println(" Testing 'findById' with 'id' 1 - Inicio");
        Cientifico cientifico = cientificoService.findById(1);
        assertAll("Entidad 'id' 1",
                ()-> assertNotNull(cientifico),
                ()-> assertEquals("Albert", cientifico.getNombres()),
                ()-> assertEquals("Einstein", cientifico.getApellidos()),
                ()-> assertFalse(cientifico.isVive())
                );
        System.out.println(" Testing 'findById' with 'id' 1 - Fin");
        System.out.println(" findByIdWithId1EnvironmentAssumeTrueCase01Test - Fin");
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Testing 'findById' with 'id' 1 - Environment 'assumeTrue' Case 02")
    void findByIdWithId1EnvironmentAssumeTrueCase02Test() {
        System.out.println(" findByIdWithId1EnvironmentAssumeTrueCase02Test - Inicio");
        System.out.println(" JAVA_HOME: " + System.getenv("JAVA_HOME"));
        assumeTrue(System.getenv("JAVA_HOME") == null, "JAVA_HOME must NOT exist");
        System.out.println(" Testing 'findById' with 'id' 1 - Inicio");
        Cientifico cientifico = cientificoService.findById(1);
        assertAll("Entidad 'id' 1",
                ()-> assertNotNull(cientifico),
                ()-> assertEquals("Albert", cientifico.getNombres()),
                ()-> assertEquals("Einstein", cientifico.getApellidos()),
                ()-> assertFalse(cientifico.isVive())
                );
        System.out.println(" Testing 'findById' with 'id' 1 - Fin");
        System.out.println(" findByIdWithId1EnvironmentAssumeTrueCase02Test - Fin");
    }

    @AfterEach
    void afterEach() {
        System.out.println("[Destruyendo CientificoService]");
        cientificoService = null;
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void afterAll() {
        System.out.println("**********************");
        System.out.println("Destruyendo Aplicacion");
        System.out.println("**********************");
    }

}
```

When the Test class is executed through the IDE (*sts4*), the `@DisplayName` values are shown as expected, and the 2nd `@Test` method is expected to be aborted due the failed assumption, it happens and is reported through the `TestAbortedException` message as follows:

```
org.opentest4j.TestAbortedException: Assumption failed: JAVA_HOME must NOT exist
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions.throwAssumptionFailed(Assumptions.java:316)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assumptions.assumeTrue(Assumptions.java:115)
    at com.manuel.jordan.service.findbyid.assumetrue.CientificoServiceFindByIdWithSystemEnvironmentAssumeTrueTests.findByIdWithId1EnvironmentAssumeTrueCase02Test(CientificoServiceFindByIdWithSystemEnvironmentAssumeTrueTests.java:88)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

The situation is when is tried through `Maven` directly by command. I already post some time ago about this situation at:

- [Maven: How show the @DisplayName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75747568/maven-how-show-the-displayname)
- [Maven: How show in terminal the abort message of a JUnit Assumption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75747380/maven-how-show-in-terminal-the-abort-message-of-a-junit-assumption)

Practically the 2 previous links, about the answers, they refer to the [Maven Surefire Plugin - Using JUnit 5 Platform](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#using-junit-5-platform) page. Thus `maven-surefire-plugin` was upgraded to series **3**.

Therefore according with [Surefire Extensions and Reports Configuration for @DisplayName](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#surefire-extensions-and-reports-configuration-for-displayname), I tried first:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <statelessTestsetReporter implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5Xml30StatelessReporter">
            <disable>false</disable>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <usePhrasedFileName>false</usePhrasedFileName>
            <usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>true</usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>
            <usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>
            <usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>
        </statelessTestsetReporter>
        <consoleOutputReporter implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5ConsoleOutputReporter">
            <disable>false</disable>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <usePhrasedFileName>false</usePhrasedFileName>
        </consoleOutputReporter>
        <statelessTestsetInfoReporter implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5StatelessTestsetInfoReporter">
            <disable>false</disable>
            <usePhrasedFileName>false</usePhrasedFileName>
            <usePhrasedClassNameInRunning>true</usePhrasedClassNameInRunning>
            <usePhrasedClassNameInTestCaseSummary>true</usePhrasedClassNameInTestCaseSummary>
        </statelessTestsetInfoReporter>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And *nothing*, the output remains being the same when the plugin is based on series **2**, such as `2.22.2`.

And according with [External extensions for the plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#external-extensions-for-the-plugin) I tried with (versions upgraded):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.fabriciorby</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-junit5-tree-reporter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <reportFormat>plain</reportFormat>
        <consoleOutputReporter>
            <disable>false</disable>   <--- changed from true to false
        </consoleOutputReporter>
        <statelessTestsetInfoReporter
            implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5StatelessTestsetInfoTreeReporter" />
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The output is as follows:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
******************
Creando Aplicacion
******************
[Obteniendo CientificoService]
 findByIdWithId1EnvironmentAssumeTrueCase01Test - Inicio
 JAVA_HOME: /home/manueljordan/java/eclipse/temurin/jdk-17.0.8+7
 Testing 'findById' with 'id' 1 - Inicio
 Testing 'findById' with 'id' 1 - Fin
 findByIdWithId1EnvironmentAssumeTrueCase01Test - Fin
[Destruyendo CientificoService]
[Obteniendo CientificoService]
 findByIdWithId1EnvironmentAssumeTrueCase02Test - Inicio
 JAVA_HOME: /home/manueljordan/java/eclipse/temurin/jdk-17.0.8+7
[Destruyendo CientificoService]
**********************
Destruyendo Aplicacion
**********************
[INFO] +--Testing Multiple 'findById' Test Methods - Environment 'assumeTrue' - 0.742 ss
[INFO] |  +-- [OK] Testing 'findById' with 'id' 1 - Environment 'assumeTrue' Case 01 - 0.588 ss
[INFO] |  '-- [??] Testing 'findById' with 'id' 1 - Environment 'assumeTrue' Case 02 - 0 ss
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[WARNING] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 1
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.341 s
[INFO] Finished at: .....
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*Just now* is possible see the `@DisplayName` as required (something that [Surefire Extensions and Reports Configuration for @DisplayName](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#surefire-extensions-and-reports-configuration-for-displayname) did not do), but does *not* appear the `TestAbortedException` message yet.

#### Question

- What is the correct configuration of `maven-surefire-plugin` **3** to show `@DisplayName` and `TestAbortedException`?

##### Extra Questions:

- Why [Surefire Extensions and Reports Configuration for @DisplayName](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#surefire-extensions-and-reports-configuration-for-displayname) configuration did not work?

Comment: I would recommend to try https://github.com/fabriciorby/maven-surefire-junit5-tree-reporter

Comment: Thank You, I tried with the settings available on that page, sadly same results, I am going to create an issue to request that feature.